# Replace every array in object by first element of that array

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a json like this:

```
   "Client" : {
        "ClientId" : "eertertwetw",
        "Username" : "c.client",
        "Names" : [
            {
                "Family" : "ClientFamilyName",
                "Given" : [
                    "ClientGivenName"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

This json is not fixed, so sometimes there are some properties and sometimes not. 
I need to replace every array inside this Json with the first element of that array. So, for example, in this case it would be like

```
   "Client" : {
        "ClientId" : "eertertwetw",
        "Username" : "c.client",
        "Names" :
            {
                "Family" : "ClientFamilyName",
                "Given" : 
                    "ClientGivenName"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Can anyone help me to find a way to do this with Typescript?

Comment: Problem statement is not clear yet, What you want `prefix` in every object?

Comment: @PardeepJain yes, it is clear. He wants to replace every array in that object by first element of that array :)

Comment: @romanSG is right. I'm searching something to create a new object with that replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried something (haven't tested it against all possible cases) but it seems like it's working.

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dquwep)** - check the console for result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I found your answer very good for what I have to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = { Client: {...} }; // your data

data = data.map(client => {
    if (!Object.hasOwnProperty(client.Names, 'Prefix')) {
        client.Names.Prefix = null;
    }
    return client;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need get the firt element in array in object.

like : `Client.Names[0].Given[0].ClientGivenName`